# completely blank console

Tags: errors, installing, mac

[image]I've now reinstalled LaTeX several times on my Mac after upgrading to the El Capitan OS.  I read the document on how to change directories and everything seems to be in the proper place.  Except when I try to compile a document, I get a completely blank console.  No error messages, nothing.  Just a blank console.  Anyone else had this problem and, if so, have you solved it?

Code here (apologies for the extraneous bits...):

```
\documentclass[paper,10pt, ]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhead{}
\lhead{} 
\chead{} 
\rhead{ \thepage} 
\lfoot{ECON 412: Introduction to Econometrics} 
\cfoot{} 
\rfoot{Fall 2015} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\newcounter{ale}
\newcommand{\abc}{\item[\alph{ale})]\stepcounter{ale}}

\newcommand{\nin}{\noindent}
\newenvironment{liste}{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\aliste}{\begin{liste} \setcounter{ale}{1}}
\newcommand{\zliste}{\end{liste}}

\newenvironment{abcliste}{\aliste}{\zliste}

\begin{document}


\begin{centering}
 {\Large Homework 6} \\
 Due Monday, November 9\\
 \end{centering}
\vspace{0.3in}
\nin \textbf{Instructions:} \textit{Homework must be written up individually, though you are allowed to work with your fellow students. Use math, graphs, or words to support your answers. Please write legibly and staple your homework.}     

\par\vspace{5ex}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 6.1, p. 129
  \item 6.2, p. 129
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post more information on what editor you're using (TeXWorks, TeXStudio, command line, etc.?) and what commands you're running? If you have a screenshot, that may be helpful too. Right now, there's probably not enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I'm using TexShop 3.51 (the 3.57 update doesn't solve the problem).  I'll attach the code next.  Can't seem to figure out how to upload a screenshot...

Comment: I was able to compile your document without any problems (on Debian GNU/Linux OS), so the problem is not with the LaTeX code.

Comment: A snapshot will be helpful.

Comment: What happens when you compile from the command line? What does `which pdflatex` give? (Or substitute your compiler of choice.) What does `echo $PATH` give? Does the link in `/Library/TeX/...` exist? (Somebody help me out here - I don't know how the path is meant to end!)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after (re-) installing MacTeX-2015. While MacTeX-2015 automatically puts

Library/TeX/texbin

into TeXShop>Preferences>Engine, and this thereby solves the "error" message one gets without this fix, there's then the blank-console problem, which you (and I) and others experience. There's a simple fix.

SOLUTION: add a forward slash at the very beginning of "Library/TeX/texbin" to get

/Library/TeX/texbin

and your problem will be solved. -Jc